# Appending javascript and css with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I want to display some form only sometimes, so I append the HTML using

```
$.html('HTML here');
```

however I need some logic and design I need to append JavaScript and CSS as well.
js code is quite long it looks horrible when it is multiline string and I don't have an option to read it from another source, is there any other option?

Comment: Why don't you have an option to read it from another source? Can you try to make an ajax call to a html file with the form and append the form where you need it? Just make sure you use correct dataType and you should be able to do it without multiline strings and messy code.

Comment: Including some code with your post usually helps.

Comment: Sorry, here it is:
    `$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "form.html",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        $('div').append(data);
      }
    });`

Comment: I want my library to be one js file - no more

Answer (score 1):

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />');
$('head').append('<script type=text/javascript" src="script.js" />');
```

or if you want to add the code and not the file the:

```
$('body').append($("<script>alert('avascript!');<\/script>")[0]);
$('body').append($("<style>.someclass{padding:10px;}<\/style>")[0]);
```

Comment: As in question, I cant read it from another source

Answer (score 0):

- If you only need to append different forms at a given time, you can put all the forms on the page and then hide/show them with jquery.
- If the javascript is for validations purposes, you can write different functions that will be called depending on the form you are submitting.
- Finally the css can be applied to each element by using css classes.

So it is not necessary to append everything as it could be written in the page from the first time. This approach is a standard for ajax applications today. It's called [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).